# requiredfield check for asp.net checkboxes in repeater?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-3.0, validation

How can I do a requiredfield check for each checkbox before postingback the asp.net page? So at least one checkbox needs to be checked.

aspx

```
    <asp:Button ID="Submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
```

Comment: Also, you should tag this with `JavaScript` since it needs to be done before you postback to the server...

Answer (score 1):

For a group of checkboxes where at least one is checked, the easiest way I know of is to use an `<asp:CustomValidator />`. Write a JavaScript validation function (to validate the checkboxes and ensure at least one is checked) and assign it to the `<asp:CustomValidator />`.

Example markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Check at least one" ClientValidationFunction="atLeastOneIsChecked"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Example JavaScript:

```
function atLeastOneIsChecked(sender, args) {
    var chk1 = document.getElementById('<%=CheckBox1.ClientId %>').checked;
    var chk2 = document.getElementById('<%=CheckBox2.ClientId %>').checked;
    var chk3 = document.getElementById('<%=CheckBox3.ClientId %>').checked;
    var chk4 = document.getElementById('<%=CheckBox4.ClientId %>').checked;

    args.IsValid = (chk1 || chk2 || chk3 || chk4);
    return args.IsValid;
}
```